# postgresql will not save array of empty arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A `user` model has a `goal` field that is an array:

```
t.integer "goal", default: [], array: true
```

A valid entry for goal is `[[],[],[]]`. If I do

```
Match.create(goal: [[],[],[]])
```

I get an exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{{},{},{}}"
DETAIL:  Unexpected "}" character.
```

I know that I can work around this by saving it as `goal: []`, but I lose information about the number of sub-arrays.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve gone from trying to store an array of numbers to an array of fixed length which includes null values or even sub arrays. Therefore, a `t.integer` field is no good. You need to use a `t.jsonb` or `t.json` field.

See the [Postgres docs on JSON datatypes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html)